# Get hold of title, text, etc. after I get through find

Tags: reactjs

It is so that I get an object back as lots based on the id specified.

Right now I try to get things done so that events can print title at HERE!

But every time I try to print it. Then it comes up with errors that make it not appear on the page.

```
function EventSingle({match, events}){
  const id = match.params.id;

  //Evt tag en samtale med lærer i morgen i forhold til findIndex vs Find?
  const event = events.find(e => e.id == id)

  console.log(event);

  console.log(event.title); //Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>HERE!</h2>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

What I want is that title and text and object from events must enter the return area.

Json here:

```
{
    "events": [{
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Hello world",
        "short_desc": "hehehe",
        "long_desc": "hehehe",
        "price": 129.00,
        "start": "05-06-2019 19.00 ETC",
        "end": "05-06-2019 21.00 ETC",
        "image": null,
        "location": {
            "venue": "x"
            "city": "aa"
        },
        "country": {
            "country": "ddd",
            "country_code": "DK"
        },
        "genre": {
            "genre": "Comedy"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that your object has an events property. So you would need to find the events property from your events object. (events.events.find(...)).

Comment: What u mean @FernandoChavezHerrera

Answer (score 0):

It should work but I can see that the json object shared by you is not valid.
Could you please try the following:

```
{
    "events": [{
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Hello world",
        "short_desc": "hehehe",
        "long_desc": "hehehe",
        "price": 129.00,
        "start": "05-06-2019 19.00 ETC",
        "end": "05-06-2019 21.00 ETC",
        "image": null,
        "location": {
            "venue": "x",
            "city": "aa"
        },
        "country": {
            "country": "ddd",
            "country_code": "DK"
        },
        "genre": {
            "genre": "Comedy"
        }
    }]
}
```

Let me know the outcome.

Link to codepen. https://codepen.io/anand-kr/pen/axrqxx

I did modify the return statement but you can see it working.

Comment: Link updated! Please try the example provided through codepen.